# How to Create a program that calculates the count of numbers that is divisible to 3 and 4 between 1 and 100?

Tags: javascript

it is hard to find a solution to this question, so I have a short way to do that. To find the count of numbers that's divisible to 3 and 4 between 1 and 100 we have a formula in Math: **|b - a|: LCM (Lowest Common Multiple) + 1**. I have all the stuff that is needed to create this program but I had a few issues with my code so I couldn't finish it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit your question to ask for help with a specific language and provide the smallest possible working example of what you currently have.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/kukiqowixi/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

```js
var totalCount3=0;
var totalCount4=0;
for(var i=1;i<=100;i++){
  if(i % 3 == 0){
    totalCount3 += 1;
  }
  if(i%4 == 0){
    totalCount4 += 1;
  }
}
console.log(totalCount3);
console.log(totalCount4);
```

Answer (score 0):

The range of values you are checking is very limited (1-100) so you can use a bruteforce approach. You can simply scanning all values from to 100 and then check if each value is divisible using the module operator. I suppose you use javascript:

```
var counter = 0;

for(var i = 1; i<=100; i++){
  if((i%3==0)||(i%4==0)){
    counter++
    }
}
console.log(counter);
```